# jQuery Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've implemented an image switch in my website. It worked fine but I broke it by altering to my wishes. The code was as following:

```
if (src) { $$('#' + id + ' a.product-image img').first().setAttribute("src", src);}
```

And i've changed it to:

```
if (src) { $$('#' + id + ' a.product-image img').first().setAttribute("src", src); 
           $$('#' + id + ' a.popup-image img').first().setAttribute("src", src); 
         }
```

I simply added a image source that need to be changed. But when I run it on my site I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
```

I've checked if the element exists and if it could by found by adding the following code to my script:

```
if('#' + id + 'popup-image' == 0){
    console.log("fail");
}else{
    console.log("found");
}
```

And it returns found everytime. I've changed my code to this:

```
$$('#' + id + ' a.popup-image img').first().setAttribute("src", src);
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of null
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `setAttribute` is a DOM node method. You are trying to use it on jQuery obj

Comment: What is the `$$` function? Note that `if('#' + id + 'popup-image' == 0){` does _not_ check if the element exists, it compares a string to the number 0, which won't ever be equal so will always log "found".

Comment: @nnnnnn I always use this method to only display something if an element exist. And it always works correctly

Comment: No it doesn't. Read my explanation of why it doesn't work again. Think about how evaluating a string could possibly check whether a DOM element exists (it can't). You can easily test this by changing the `'popup-image'` part of that `if` to `'blah'` - it'll still log "found". You have to pass that string to a function that looks for the DOM element (e.g., to the `$$()` function, whatever it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if an element exists you should've used the code:

```
if($$('#' + id + 'popup-image').length > 0){
    console.log("found");
}else{
    console.log("fail");
}
```

To set the attribute you should

```
if (src) { $$('#' + id + ' a.product-image img').first().attr("src", src);
           $$('#' + id + ' a.popup-image img').first().attr("src", src); 
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the JavaScript `setAttribute()` function, you have to access the HTMLElement within your jQuery object by referencing the first item of its array, `[0]`, like so:

```
 $('#' + id + ' a.product-image img')[0].setAttribute("src", src);
```

Calling `first()` will return a jQuery object; with this approach you have to use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** , as there is no `setAttribute()` method in jQuery.

Try:

```
 $('#' + id + ' a.product-image img').eq(0).attr("src", src);
```

or:

```
$('#' + id + ' a.product-image img:first').attr("src", src);
```

or you can use [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) which takes an index argument, and passing 0 will return first element:

```
$('#' + id + ' a.product-image img').get(0).attr("src", src);
```

Comment: it means `first()` returned `null` (no element)

Comment: The jQuery method `first()` won't ever return `null`. (It can return an empty jQuery object.)

Comment: i mean to say that no element found so it is **undefined**

Comment: jQuery's `first()` won't return `undefined` either. Also, `.get(0)` returns a DOM element not a jQuery object, so you can't chain `.attr()` after `.get()`. (`.get(0)` _will_ return `undefined` if there was no matching element.)